# Lower byte of Unicode similar to ASCII

Tags: java

I am studying for an upcoming exam and in my study guide I am asked if the lower byte of Unicode have same coding scheme. In UTF-8 there are  1-4 bytes per code point while ASCII values are encoded as ASCII using 1 byte. Still not quite sure what that statement means.

Comment: That will be true.. I think each UTF8 char is 4 byte. For example Chinese letter, Korean Letter.. they will use 4 full byte.   But in UTF8 just simple char like alphabet use just 1  byte. remain 3bytes will be zero.

Comment: @GaryYKim actually, just 2. What you're talking about is surrogate pairs.

Comment: Have you tried reading about what UTF-8 is?  The official definition is [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-3).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) also describes it.  There's even [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm).  In short, each character can take up as many as 21 bits, and UTF-8 is a strategy for spreading those bits out in multiple bytes so they can be reliably parsed.

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou oh~~ thanks.